# How to extract specific element from vector using for loop in R

Tags: r, list

I have a vector and would like to extract a specific element of this vector using `for` loop function in R.

Here is my try:

```
par <- list(0.5,0.5)
par2 <- list(0,0.4)
Param <- c(par, par2)
s <- length(par)
m <- length(par2)
for(i in 1:2){
  par[[i]] <- Param[[i]]
  par2[[i]] <- Param[(length(par)+1):length(Param)]
}
```

I got this:

>

```
 par2
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.4


> par
[[1]]
[1] 0.5

[[2]]
[1] 0.5
```

the result of `par` is correct. However, `par2` is wrong. It is repeated.

I would like to get this:

`par[[1]] <- 0.5` , `par[[2]] <- 0.5`, `par2[[1]] <-0` and `par2[[2]]<- 0.4`.

Any help, please?

Comment: Your code is working for me, this is the output: par2
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.4

Comment: @Terru_theTerror Yes, it works now. However, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you index with a sequence both times in the loop

```
Param[(length(par)+1):length(Param)]
```

You can just use `+i`.

```
for(i in 1:2){
  par[[i]] <- Param[[i]]
  par2[[i]] <- Param[[length(par)+i]]
}

> par
[[1]]
[1] 0.5

[[2]]
[1] 0.5

> par2
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0.4
```